# Conditions for positive definiteness for a class of matrices induced by a semimetric

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, metric-spaces, fourier-analysis, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a set, and let $d:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a semimetric on that set (i.e. $\forall x,y\in X$, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)\ge 0$, and $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$).

I seek conditions on $X$ and $d$ which are sufficient (and ideally necessary) for the following proposition:

- $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \in X$, the
  matrix $M=(m_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$ with elements
  $m_{ij}=\exp{[-d(x_i,x_j)]}$ is positive definite.

Possible avenues of attack:

- When $X=\mathbb{R}$, and $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric, then these matrices are the covariance matrices of samples from standard Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes, and hence positive definite.
- When $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, and $d$ is again the usual Euclidean metric, then, if I understand both result 504 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), and [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) correctly, then again $M$ is guaranteed to be positive definite. (Honestly, I found the previously linked page rather incomprehensible, but the simple summary on the Wikipedia page for positive-definite functions gave me hope.)
- A direct approach via induction on $n$ may be possible, perhaps using the Schur-complement conditions for positive definite functions, and the fact that in the univariate case, the $M$ matrices have a tri-diagonal inverse.

The Bochner's theorem approach suggests we need $X$ to be a locally compact abelian group, and $d$ to come from a norm on $X$. Is this actually sufficient? Are such strong assumptions necessary? It's not even immediately clear to me that the triangle inequality should be necessary.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: This is   related to Schoenberg's theorem on isometric embedding into a Hilbert space: see [page 9 here](http://lptms.u-psud.fr/ressources/publis/2008/new/Distance%20matrices%20and%20isometric%20embeddings.pdf). Every subset of a Hilbert space, with the restriction metric, has this property. I don't believe that a LCA group is a sufficient: the torus might already be a counterexample, but I haven't checked.

Comment: That paper is very useful, thanks, @Rafflesia-arnoldii. I will have to study the paper carefully in order to see the consequences of the link to Schoenberg's theorem, and your suggested counter-example, but it's great to have at least the Euclidean and spherical cases explicitly covered.

Comment: The fact that the matrices are positive definite in the exp(-r^2) case is interesting too. Has the stochastic process associated with this case been studied?